# Attach File (ContentDocumentLink) to Email

Tags: contentdocumentlink

I'm creating and sending one email via APEX.
However I havent found any documentation helping me to attach a File (ContentDocumentLink), not an Attachment to an Messaging.SingleEmailMessage.

The query that I use to retrieve those files is:

```
select id from  ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId = 'a2T1l000000TRuVEAW'
```

Is that possible? If not, how to convert those files to attachments, so that I could add than to the email. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to leverage your ContentDocumentLink to add an email attachment, but you'll need to perform a few steps to get there. I'll try to break it down to point you in the right direction.

**Step 1: Query the ContentDocument record**

The first thing you'll need to do is query for the related **ContentDocument** record. If you already know that the entity Id belongs to a ContentDocument, you can **skip to step 2**. Otherwise, get the ContentDocumentId from the **ContentDocumentLink** like so:

```
List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlList = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :entityId];
```

**Step 2: Query the ContentVersion record**

The **ContentVersion** object has a field called *VersionData* that contains the actual data needed to build your email attachment:

```
List<ContentVersion> cvList = [SELECT VersionData, FileExtension FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = :cdlList[0].ContentDocumentId AND IsLatest = true];
```

Also, note that I've added the *IsLatest* flag as a condition within the query since a ContentDocument can have many ContentVersions, and you'll generally want the latest version of that file.

**Step 3: Build the attachment**

Build the email attachment using the ContentVersion record that was queried:

```
Blob fileData = cvList[0].VersionData; // <= This step converts the version data into a blob for the attachment
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment emlAtt = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
emlAtt.setFilename('MyFile.' + cvList[0].FileExtension);
emlAtt.setBody(fileData);
```

**Final Notes**

From step 3, you should be able to build your email message object and add the attachment to be sent off.

Also, due to governor limits, keep in mind that Apex only has so much space allotted (I.e. Heap space) for loading data. Ideally, the file you're trying to send wouldn't be larger than a few megabytes.

Comment: perfect answer my friend! I hope that this helps someone else like it did to me

Answer (score 4):

The key method you want to use is the `Messaging.setEntityAttachments()` method.

This method accepts: `Array of IDs of Document, ContentVersion, or Attachment items to attach to the email.`

See also:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setEntityAttachments

You'll therefore need to get your ContentVersion Ids from your ContentDocumentLink query.

E.g.

```
List<String> contentVersionIds =  new List<String>();

for(ContentDocumentLink thisCdl : [SELECT ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = 'a2T1l000000TRuVEAW') {
    contentVersionIds.add(thisCdl.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId);
}

 mySingleEmailMessage.setEntityAttachments(contentVersionIds);
```